# Angular ReactiveForm Error Association

Tags: typescript, angular-2+

I want to associate an error message to a Validator and not have to in the html check for a specific error. aka *ngIf="controls.name.required".  I've seen generic error message helpers that build up an javascript object with an index and a message that goes with that index.  What I want is to actually associate the error message with the validation result.

This only works for ReactiveForms but I'm wrapping the Validator Result and tagging in the message into the ValidationErrors result.

```
import { ValidatorFn, ValidationErrors, AbstractControl, AsyncValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { map, filter, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

function isObservable(observerable: ValidationErrors | Observable<ValidationErrors>): observerable is Observable<ValidationErrors> {
  return observerable.pipe && typeof observerable.pipe === 'function';
}

// @dynamic
export class ValidatorHelpers {
  // Validator that wraps another validator and adds a message property to the ValidationErrors payload
  static addMessage(innerValidator: ValidatorFn, message: string | ((validationErrors: ValidationErrors) => string)): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      const result = innerValidator(control);
      if (result) {
        if (typeof message !== 'string') {
          const func = message as ((validationErrors: ValidationErrors) => string);
          message = func(result);
        }
        const newObj: ValidationErrors = Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(result)
          .filter((k) => result[k])
          .map(k => ({ [k]: { ...result[k], message } })));
        return newObj;
      }
      return null;
    };
  }

  static asyncAddMessage(innerValidator: AsyncValidatorFn, message: string | ((validationErrors: ValidationErrors) => string)): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return async (control: AbstractControl) => {
      const innerResult = await innerValidator(control);
      if (innerResult) {
        const getMessage = (errors: ValidationErrors): string => {
          if (typeof message !== 'string') {
            const func = message as ((validationErrors: ValidationErrors) => string);
            return func(errors);
          } else {
            return message;
          }
        };

        const result = (errors: ValidationErrors): ValidationErrors => {
          return Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(errors)
            .filter(x => errors[x])
            .map(x => ({ [x]: { ...errors[x], message: getMessage(errors), value: control.value } })));
        };
        if (isObservable(innerResult)) {
          return innerResult.pipe(
            filter(x => Boolean(x)),
            map(x => result(x)),
            take(1)).toPromise();
        } else {
          return result(innerResult);
        }
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
}
```

Now when validation comes back it has a new property called message to the ValidationErrors. when I build my FormGroup I can add validation message as

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.createFormGroup = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', [ValidationHelpers.addMessage(Validators.required, 'Name is required')]]
  })
}
```

In the html I can get the error for each field as so

```
<div *ngIf="(controls.name.dirty || controls.name.touched) && controls.name.invalid" class="invalid-feedback d-block">
  <div data-error-for="name" *ngFor="let error of controls.name.errors | keyvalue">
    {{error.value.message}}
  </div>
</div>
```

This way when validations get changed don't have to update html or a error to message mapping object and the message gets returned back with the error.